# Excel VBA Programming handling formulae

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub RefreshBenchmarks_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("INDEX CHANGES")

If Not IsError(Application.Offset(ws!S3, _
                           Application.Match(Worksheets("ASX200").B8, _
                           ws.Range("CONSTITUENT_CHANGES"), 0), 0, 1, 1) = "D" _
                           And _
                           Application.Offset(ws!N3, _
                           Application.Match(Worksheets("ASX200").B8, _
                           Range("CONSTITUENT_CHANGES"), 0), 0, 1, 1) = "Y") Then

    Worksheets("ASX200").J8 = 0
```

I am new to vba programming, can someone please explain what is the mistake here. The error says object doesn't not support this property or method. It stops at the If statement. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Start by making this change `Worksheets("ASX200").B8` >> `Worksheets("ASX200").Range("B8")`

Comment: Sorry it didn't work

Comment: Application.Offset...?  Offset is a property of a Range object.

Comment: If I don't use Application.offset it says sub or object not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but something like this...

```
Private Sub RefreshBenchmarks_Click()

    Dim wsIdx As Worksheet, wsAsx As Worksheet, v, m

    Set wsIdx = Worksheets("INDEX CHANGES")
    Set wsAsx = Worksheets("ASX200")

    m = Application.Match(wsAsx.Range("B8").Value, _
                          wsIdx.Range("CONSTITUENT_CHANGES"), 0)

    If Not IsError(m) Then

        If wsIdx.Range("S3").Offset(m, 0).Value = "D" And _
           wsIdx.Range("N3").Offset(m, 0).Value = "Y" Then

            wsAsx.Range("J8").Value = 0

        End If


    End If

End Sub
```